# Directly download video from url instead of playing it on the browser

Tags: node.js, cors

I am making a website that takes a youtube url and lets the user download it in mp4 format. I have tried doing this by using the ytdl module which gives a set of urls to use. I have tried using and  tag but got no results. I always get a cors error that states `Missing allow origin header`. I tried searching the web for results but found nothing. I use xmlhttprequest. I have also tried using a package called download.js but that did not work either.

Edit: I have added a header in my xhr request `xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")`

Thank you!